# getting error for Could not find bcrypt-3.1.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, bcrypt

I created one app with device gem than run bundle instal.

than after i am trying to run this command

```
rails generate devise:install
```

but i am getting error

```
Could not find bcrypt-3.1.11 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gem...
```

I did `bundle install`

I tried this `gem install bcrypt` to install this gem

I tried to `bundle update` and than run

```
bundle exec rails generate devise:install
```

but still i am getting same error.

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'devise'
```

Comment: use this code :  `gem install bcrypt -v 3.1.11`

Comment: After installing `gem install bcrypt`, what does that error says?

Comment: @Udaykumardas i did this still same error. :(

Comment: Which ruby version you are using?

Comment: @AmitSharma ruby-2.2.3

Comment: specify `ruby '2.2.3'` on top of your gen file after `source`

Comment: also please execute `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list` command on terminal and paste the result,

Comment: @AmitSharma please create chatroom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106191/discussion-between-p-m-and-amit-sharma).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncomment this line of your `Gemfile`:

```
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

and run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all `spring` from your `Gemfile`.

```
gem "spring"
gem "spring-commands-rspec"
```

Run `bundle install`

Not sure why I tried to do another application with spring. :(

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle update`

I just experienced the same problem. I did what @Uday kumar das suggested and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It took me few hours to get this done but please feel free to share it.The root problem here is that Ruby itself comes with `bcrypt` version 3.1.5 which is having bugs with the newer updates.

However when you install or uninstall the `bcrypt` you are leaving behind `bcrypt-ruby` which it always asks for first and hence all what you are doing won't go through, so what to do?

1. uninstall `bcrypt` and `bcrypt-ruby` by running these two commands:

   ```
   gem uninstall bcrypt and gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
   ```
2. Install it again with:

   ```
   gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
   ```

In your Gemfile write:

```
gem 'bcrypt','~>3.1.11'
```

NOW as I write these lines the latest version is `3.1.11` but whatever version is updated just add it from their gem page. Run bundle install and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I fixed the problem by cloning the project into another folder and running `bundle install` in the newly cloned project.  Then I was able to run the `rails` command again.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem with bcrypt 3.1.12 after installing devise 4.6.2.  I don't believe this is specific to crypt or devise, I believe this is a spring problem as others have indicated.

I was able to solve this problem simply by stopping spring and rerunning the rails generator with

```
spring stop
rails g devise:install
```

Try that before doing anything destructive or intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your gemfile this code:

```
gem 'bcrypt'
```

and then run `bundle install` in console.

Comment: Could not find rake-11.1.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: i did this gem install rake-11.1.1
but getting this error

 ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake-11.1.1' (>= 0) in any repository

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I uninstalled all versions of bcrypt, with gem uninstall bcrypt and select option 3 (if it exists), and uninstalled all versions of bcrypt-ruby gem with gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby and select option 3 (if it exists), then I installed bcrypt using gem install bcrypt --platform = ruby and I added this line gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7' in Gemfile. It worked right.

Answer (score 0):

After search throught a lot of responses, for me this is the solution on Rails-5.0.2:

```
spring stop
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gem pristine -a
bundle install
bundle update
```

solved this for me

I had these lines commented out as well due to a previous try, not sure if it helped.

```
# gem 'spring'
# gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
```